# Микроразметка страницы услуг с ценами ( schema.org )

Tags: schema.org, микроразметка

друзья! Возникла необходимость на странице списка услуг с ценами сделать микроразметку. То есть на странице имеется таблица с названием услуги и ценой. Буду крайне благодарен если кто-то подскажет или толкнёт в правильном направлении. Пробовал гуглить, но всегда натыкался на разметку только карточки товара. Как сделать правильно разметку для списка услуг?